# Is there a way to password protect the ability to unhide a tab on a google sheet using an appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, password-protection

Note: I'm fairly new to appscript. The search was the first thing I've ever written. So please feel free to assume my knowledge base of appscript is small.

**Short version**:
Is there a way that I can make an appscript trigger upon trying to unhide a specific tab in a google sheet?

**Long Version**:
I have a google sheet that I created where users can input criteria to search a database that is in a separate google sheet. In order for the search to work, they need editing privileges to the database in the other google sheet (The search filters the database by condition, inserts the results into a new tab in the database google sheet, copies the results and pastes into the search google sheet, and then deletes the tab it created in the database google sheet. This was my work around since copyto does not work between two separate google sheet files - only within the same google sheets file).

I would like to protect the database though. I can hide the tab with all the data in the database sheet, and the search still works. But someone who knows how to search for hidden tabs could go easily go into the database file and unhide the sheet, edit it, copy, print, etc. I would like to prevent that.

Is there a way that I can make an appscript trigger upon trying to unhide that specific tab and ask the user for a passcode? If the passcode is correct it continues to unhide so the user with permission may edit the database. If the passcode is incorrect it pops up a notification that they do not have permission to view the tab and hides the tab again?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the installable `onChange` trigger, more info here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

The `onChange` trigger runs after a user changes the structure of the spreadsheet whereas the `onEdit` trigger runs after a user edits the value of a cell in a spreadsheet.

That being said, the trigger seems to run *after* the user's action completes (ie *after* they unhide the sheet in your example), so they would probably still be able to see the data for a bit before any of your code runs, this may not be a real issue for you, just letting you know. If that is a concern, you can make the data white (or whatever the background cell color is), so that it is effectively invisible.

I haven't tried this out, but I think you should be able to do something like this:

1. Write a function that checks if sheet with sensitive data is visible
   via `sheet.isSheetHidden()` (the `onChange` trigger has a
   `changeType` value, but unfortunately it's not exhaustive and for
   unhiding a tab it has a value of `OTHER`)
2. If it's visible, immediately hide it via `sheet.hideSheet()` and
   open a simple dialog box asking for a password via
   `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog()` (if you do not want to
   have to enter the password everytime you interact with it, you can
   maybe add a condition against your email address)
3. If the password is correct, call `sheet.showSheet()` and change the text color so the user can see it.
4. If the password is incorrect, throw some warning.

**Edit to add**
Just wanted to also mention that you said that `copyTo` doesn't work between separate files, but there is a difference between [range.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)) and [sheet.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) the latter of which should be able to copy data between different files. Not sure if this matters for your use case, but just wanted to let you know.